# Thin grey line issue on chrome - Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

The grey line is pretty much unintended from my side. I didn't put any outlines or borders to the elements but still, I can see these in Chrome (Android, OS X and Windows). When I hover over it sometimes flickers and creates more lines, its pretty much some kind of rendering issue. I have tested it on other people's chrome browser. Same happens. And I'm using bootstrap.

`>`
https://jsfiddle.net/pjxax7ox/1/

[image]

Comment: Kindly post code / create fiddle.

Comment: Is it just chrome or other browsers too? If so, which ones?

Comment: It works fine on OS X safari browser, but not one chrome

Comment: i found no problem, works fine for me !

Comment: JS Fiddle didn't allowed me to upload image assets aswell, please change the body background image path and then try again, You will find it.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
*, *:focus {outline:none}
```

Comment: Sorry that didn't work as its not a coded bug, its something else. Those lines are oddly working in the website.

Comment: Have you checked any other browser or let me know which font are you using. Some time google font creates an issue or might slices have gone wrong

Comment: Change the font and check it once. Just to confirm if it is not a font issue

Comment: Its not a font issue, i tried resetting the to default bootstrap one.

Comment: Bootstrap version?

Comment: Bootstrap version is 3.3.7